# Select elements from jQuery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a c"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a c"></div>
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a f"></div>


var selection = jQuery('div.a');
```

Does anybody know a way to select divs with class="b" from `var selection`
without iterating through array's elements and checking their class one by one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
selection.filter('.b');
```