# Getting specific objects from a selected list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I'll have to hit myself in the head after that.

Let's say I have html like this:

```
<div class="some-class"></div>
<span class="some-class"></span>
```

Somewhere I select items like this:

```
var items = $(".some-class");
```

And somewhere later I would like to get only the divs from the `items`. I know I could use:

```
var divs = $("div.some-class");
```

But is there a simple way, without doing more selections or iterating through elements by `.each`? Something like `items.someFunction("div")`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select elements from jQuery selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491558/select-elements-from-jquery-selection)

Comment: Yep, looks like I made an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var items = $(".some-class"),
    divs = items.filter("div");
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you. Now, time for the head-hitting part.

Comment: When you're done hitting your head, please consider accepting my answer if it was to your satisfaction!